# Request canceling when page change in core javascript

Tags: javascript, http, browser, request

I have a question about request canceling. I have a website and i want to track user actions. Because of this, i added click listeners to buttons. When a button clicked, i'm sending http request a backend server. But when button action going out the my website (such as 404 error page no matter) http request is canceling and not reach the backend server. So i'm losing the button click events.

How can i solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem this way;

https://balpha.de/2012/03/javascript-concurrency-and-locking-the-html5-localstorage/

I changed this code a little bit. I created a new function called "runOnce" and before function started i added a unique id of browser tab to local storage and i check again this id is mine. If two or three browser tab accessed the local storage in same time, which one matches same if, this tab will be run the given function.

Thanks,
Murat